# Does dynamic import in Javascript change the way how to import a library/component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a few libraries which I want to import and configure after login. However if I want to use it, I need to import it dynamically every time I use it. Is there any way to say "Import this and on every other use, import it synchronously"?

Let me explain. Let's say that I have a few places where I want to use Auth module of AWS Amplify library. I do know that after login, I need to import it dynamically like this

```
...
const Auth = (await import('@aws-amplify/Auth')).default;
...
```

But any other use case is after login. Do I still need to use it like this or is there any other approach to import it synchronously after that?

Comment: `import` *statements* (as opposed to the `import` function) are statically analyzed by the browser (it isn't really synchronous under the hood, but your code can treat them that way), so no. It's either all static, or all dynamic. However the download is cached, it won't actually hit your server (unless you do some ServiceWorker magic) after the first dynamic import.

Comment: So upside is that I'll save initial download size but downside is that code is not so clear. Right?

Comment: Yes. There are also some security implications of not downloading chunks of code to un-verified users.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Posted it as an answer, if you like it please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` *statements* (as opposed to the `import` function) are statically analyzed by the browser (it isn't really synchronous under the hood, but your code can treat them that way), so no. It's either all static, or all dynamic. However the download is cached, it won't actually hit your server (unless you do some ServiceWorker magic) after the first dynamic import. There are also some security implications of not downloading chunks of code to un-verified users.